# Poor collision performance pygame

Tags: python, pygame, collision

I am wring a fairly basic 2d top down dungeon crawler type game in python, using pygame. Everything is going well, except for collision. Right now, I have a tilemap system that reads in a tilesheet, and then draws the correct image onto the screen. I'm trying to add collision to all 'wall type' images, so I built a function that draws rectangles every time there's a wall, and then they get added to a list. Here is my add_collider function:

```
rect_list = []

def add_collider(window, x, y):
    rect = pygame.rect = (x*32, y*32, 32, 32)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, [255, 0, 0], rect, 1)
    rect_list.append(rect)
```

Then in my main game loop, I can get check if my player rectangle intersects with any of my colliders. This works fine, except the game slows down to a halt after about 10 seconds of running. I figure this is because I'm running through a for loop of about 30-40 objects 30 times a second(the framerate of the game). Here's the game loop:

```
while run:
    clock.tick(30)
    #player.get_collider() returns a rectangle around the player,
    #essentially the hitbox of the player
    for c in collider.get_collider():
        if player.get_collider().colliderect(c):
            print('Collide')
            #just setting the player's position to 400,400 for now until I figure this out
            player.x = 400
            player.y = 400

    redrawGameWindow()
```

There's got to be a better way. For all I know, this could be a competently wrong/bad way of doing things. If I need to redo my collision logic, that's fine, I just want better performance. Thanks for any help or tips.

Comment: For sure *"a for loop of about 30-40 objects 30 times a second"* won't explain this rapid performance drop down. Note, that's just 1200 collision tests (`colliderect`) per second. Do you add the rectangles once per frame (`rect_list.append(rect)`) and the list grows into the infinite?

Comment: do you clear `rect_list` before you add elements in new frame ? Print `len(rect_list)` in every frame to see how many elements you have.

Comment: This is unrelated to the current issue, but when your maps get bigger it may be worthwhile to partition all your map-objects into a quadtree or suchlike to make searching for collisions more efficient.  Or maybe only check collisions within *N* units of your player.

Comment: @Rabbid76 that was it! Thank you so much, I don't know how I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 0):

For sure "a for loop of about 30-40 objects 30 times a second" won't explain this rapid performance drop down. Note, that's just 1200 collision tests (`colliderect`) per second.
However you add anew rectangles to the list once per frame (`rect_list.append(rect)`) and the list grows into the infinite. The rapidly growing list causes the performance issue.
Create the list of rectangles once in advance or clear the list (`rect_list.clear()`) in every frame.